# как записать значения чисел с динамически созданных textbox в отдельные массивы?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

```
    public void CreateColsTextBox()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width_of_nonogram; i++)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Text = "Col " + (i + 1);
            Point p = new Point(20, 30*i);
            textBox.Location = p;
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }

    }
    public void CreateRowsTextBox()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < height_of_nonogram; i++)
        {
            TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
            textBox1.Text = "Row " + (i + 1);
            Point p = new Point(200, 30*i);
            textBox1.Location = p;
            this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9N1y.png

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо создать массив TextBox и создавать каждый из них, например, `textboxes[i] = new TextBox();`. И через него сначала написать col 1 и т.д / row 1 и т.д через `textboxes[i].Text`. Дальше если вам надо записать все значения в массив, берете и в цикле перебираете textboxes `for(int i = 0; i <= textboxes.Lenght - 1; i++)` и записываете `textboxes[i].Text` в массив. Надеюсь, что помог.